# HMR - Update check failed: Error: Manifest request to url timed out

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, react-hot-loader, hot-module-replacement

Trying to setup HMR but running into this error:

> [HMR] Update check failed: Error: Manifest request to
>   http://localhost:8080/bdfcd3cc99a34de2ac8c.hot-update.json timed out.
>       at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange
>
> GET http://localhost:8080/bdfcd3cc99a34de2ac8c.hot-update.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My webpack config looks like this:

```
  output: {
    // path: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: ['.ec2.pin220.com'],
    // 0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces. The public port is 8080 which is served
    // by nginx and proxied to the internal webpack port of 10005.
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 10005,
    hot: true,
    hotOnly: true,
    compress: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }
```

Webpack output looks like this:

[image]